# Contour integration to evaluate a real-valued integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I am evaluating this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x(x^2+1)^2}\,dx$$

with the formula

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \sin(sx) dx = 2\pi \sum\text{Re } \text{Res}[f(z) e^{isz}]$$

where the sum is over the residues in upper half plane.

So since the only two singularities that are inside the upper half plane are at $z = 0$ and $z=i$, I found that

$$\begin{align}
2\pi \sum\text{Re } \text{Res}\left(f(z) e^{isz}\right) &= 2 \pi \left(\text{Re }  \text{Res}_{z= 0}\left[\frac{1}{z (z^2+1)^2} e^{i z}\right]
+ \text{Re } \text{Res}_{z= i}\left[\frac{1}{z (z^2+1)^2} e^{i z}\right]\right) \\\\
  &=2 \pi \left(1 + \frac{-3}{4e}\right)
\end{align}$$

I am pretty sure that I calculated the two residues correctly, since in mathematica

```
Residue[E^(I z)/(z (z^2 + 1)^2), {z, 0}]
```

is $1$ and

```
Residue[E^(I z)/(z (z^2 + 1)^2), {z, I}]
```

is $\frac{-3}{4e}$

But evaluating the integral

```
Integrate[Sin[x]/(x (x^2 + 1)^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

mathematica gives $\pi - \frac{3 \pi}{2e}$.

I am wondering if this is because I did something wrong somewhere or if it is because mathematica gives the wrong answer.

Thank you!

Comment: Note: $0$ is not in the upper half plane.  But the combination $\sin x/x$ has no singularity at $x=0$.  Maple agrees with Mathematica on the answer.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is analytic.  But $\frac{e^{iz}}{z}$ has a pole at $z=0$.  The contour must either encircle $z=0$, in which case the residue at $z=0$ is implicated, or not encircle the origin, in which case the residue is not implicated.  Typically, we deform the contour so as not to encircle the pole (no residue).  But the contribution to the value of the integral from the deformation around the pole is equal to $1/2$ of $2\pi i $ times the residue.

Comment: You must use $\displaystyle\color{red}{\Im}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x} \color{red}{- 1}\right)$ instead of $\displaystyle\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}$. Otherwise, the integral diverges because of the $\displaystyle x$ factor in the denominator. The $\displaystyle\color{red}{-1}$ term doesn't change the final result because $\displaystyle\Im\left(\color{red}{-1}\right) = {\large 0}.\quad$ See my answer.

Comment: @dracxxx Please feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit of course. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The inclusion of the residue at $z=0$ is not correct.**  Rather, we begin by writing

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)^2}\,dx=\text{Im}\left(\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x(x^2+1)^2}\,dx\right)$$

where the Cauchy Principal Value is given by

$$\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x(x^2+1)^2}\,dx=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{e^{ix}}{x(x^2+1)^2}\,dx$$

---

Next, we move to the complex plane.  Ler $R>1$, $\varepsilon>0$, and $C$ be the contour in the upper-half plane that is comprised as $(i)$ the straight line paths from $-R$ to $-\varepsilon$ and from $\varepsilon$ to $R$, $(ii)$ the semi-circular arc centered at $z=0$ with radius $\varepsilon$ from $-\varepsilon$ to $\varepsilon$, and $(iii)$ the semi-circular arc centered at $z=0$ with radius $R$ from $R$ to $-R$.  Note that $z=0$ is excluded from the interior region bounded by $C$.

Then, we have can write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C}\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)^2}\,dz&=\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x(x^2+1)^2}\,dx\\\\
&+\int_{\pi}^0 \frac{e^{i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}}}{\varepsilon e^{i\phi}((\varepsilon e^{i\phi})^2+1)^2}\,i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_0^{\pi} \frac{e^{iR e^{i\phi}}}{R e^{i\phi}((R e^{i\phi})^2+1)^2}\,iR e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag1
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$, the last integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches $0$.

As $\varepsilon\to0^+$, the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches $-i\pi$.

Since $C$ has excluded the $z=0$, the only residue implicated is at $z=i$.  Hence, we find

$$\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x(x^2+1)^2}\,dx=i\pi +\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)^2}, z=i\right)\tag2$$

Now, calculate the residue at $z=i$ and take the imaginary part of both sides of $(2)$.  Can you finish now?

Answer (score 0):

Since $z=0$ is a single pole of $f(z)$ on the boundary of the upper semicircle, it should be multiplied in $\pi$ rather than $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x\pars{x^{2} + 1}^{2}}\,\dd x} =
\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic x} - 1\over x\pars{x^{2} + 1}^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\Im\braces{2\pi\ic\,\lim_{x \to \ic}\,\totald{}{x}
\bracks{\pars{x - \ic}^{2}\,{\expo{\ic x} - 1\over x\pars{x^{2} + 1}^{2}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pi\,\Re\braces{\lim_{x \to \ic}\,\totald{}{x}
\bracks{{\expo{\ic x} - 1\over x\pars{x + \ic}^{2}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pi\,\Re\bracks{\lim_{x \to \ic}\
{\expo{\ic x}\pars{\ic x^{2} - 4x - \ic} + 3x + \ic \over
x^{2}\,\pars{x + \ic}^{3}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\pi - {3\pi \over 2\expo{}}} \approx 1.4080
\\ &
\end{align}